# How to store array list of accounts in android?

Tags: java, android

I am using this method to get the user accounts and it is working fine .Now i want to store it a variable and i have to print the user accounts.How can i do that?

```
 private String getFirstAccount() {
            Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(HomeScreen.this).getAccounts();

            for (Account account : accounts) {
                if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                    String possibleEmail = account.name;

                    return possibleEmail;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

For eg: If i am getting three user accounts i want to store three accounts in a variable and   print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        ArrayList<Account> tempList = new ArrayList<Account>();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                templist.add(account.name);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(tempList);
        return tempList; //Returning an empty list is better than returning null
```

Comment: i am getting error at templist.add(account.name);

Comment: it should be templist.add(account);

Comment: no the Arraylist should be a string